# How to (edit or process ) the message from the user before being classified which intent by rasa-nlu model?

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am new to RASA.. I read the last updated documentation Rasa 1.0
but I don't know how to process the message of the user before nlu-model
I would like to do things like stemming spellchecking words etc ...

I appreciate any code example with spaCy library :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rasa already comes with a few pre-processing **components** like [Tokenizers](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/#tokenizers) and you can [include them in your configuration file of the NLU pipeline](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/choosing-a-pipeline/)

For tasks like stemming and spell-checker, they are currently out of scope of Rasa NLU. The developer has to pre-process the input and pass the processed text as a string to NLU pipeline for parsing.

Nevertheless here are a few resources you can checkout -

- [Tutorial](https://stackabuse.com/python-for-nlp-tokenization-stemming-and-lemmatization-with-spacy-library/) on common pre-processing tasks with python and spacy.
- [Hunspell](https://github.com/tokestermw/spacy_hunspell) spell checker and integration with Spacy